# Select the first drop down the related drop down must be displayed

Tags: knockout.js

```
    var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ko.observableArray([
    {
    "name": "10th", "subcategories": [
    { "name": "SSC" },
    { "name": "CBSE" }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "12th", "subcategories": [{
    "name": "MPC"
    }, { "name": "BPC" }]
    }
    ]);
    self.selected_category = ko.observable();
    self.selected_sub_category = ko.observable();
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I'm selecting first dropdown which has 2 values like SSC and 12th so second dropdown must be displayed based on the first dropdown in the first row.When I click add button first dropdown is binding correctly, but the second dropdown is having the values as selected in the first row. I need the second dropdown to bind the values depending on the other selection like second row I have selected 12th so second drop down should have "MPC" and "BPC" as its values not "SSC" and "CBSE"

Comment: Your html code would help to see how you are binding and what might be wrong. even better If you can add a jsFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamy/Z6Paf/ This is my fiddle .. I have tried in the fiddle but the JS is not working .. I'm working on this from many days but have no correct solution for this...

Comment: After adding the KO regerence to your fiddle and fixing the messed up parenthesis in your code your fiddle is working: http://jsfiddle.net/WUEsp/

Comment: Thank you for the changes.. but I think you dint find the add button on the top of the table. The blue color button type is my button, when I select the dropdown value for the first time it is working,but after clicking on the add button and I select a different value other than the value I have selected in the first drop down,it is not working. Hope you understand my issue.